# Time validations (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, validation, time

I have a form (Using JavaScript) in which users are supposed to enter information like their work start time, break start time, break end time and work end time. I have 4 textboxes for this purpose. Time entered into the textbox is in `hhmm` format (24-hour only).

Requirements:

```
1. The break times (start and end) must be within the work start and end time.
2. Break start must be before break end time.
3. Users can take up work shifts during the day or even overnight.
4. Work time(excluding breaks) should be less than 8 hours and greater than 4 hours.
```

So some typical valid entries would be:

```
User1-
Start time: 0900
Break start time:1300
Break end time:1400
End time:1600

User2-
Start time:2200
Break start time:2300
Break end time:2330
End time:0400
```

Some invalid entries would be:

```
Case1 - Break start before break end
 Start time:2200
 Break start time: 2330
 Break end time: 2300
 End time:0400   

Case 2 -Breaks outside work time

 Start time:2200
 Break start time:1830
 Break end time: 1900
 End time:0400
```

I'm having trouble writing the validation code (JavaScript) for requirements 1,2 & 3. Please help me out.

Here's what I've got so far. (Please note: I cannot use DATE objects.)

```
        var wrkSt = getElement('TB1').value;
        var wrkSt_hr = parseFloat(wrkSt.substr(0,2));
        var wrkSt_mn= parseFloat(wrkEd.substr(2,2));

        var brkSt = getElement('TB2').value;
        var brkSt_hr = parseFloat(brkSt.substr(0,2));
        var brkSt_mn= parseFloat(brkEd.substr(2,2));

        var brkEd = getElement('TB3').value;
        var brkEd_hr = parseFloat(brkSt.substr(0,2));
        var brkEd_mn= parseFloat(brkEd.substr(2,2));

        var wrkEd = getElement('TB4').value;
        var wrkEd_hr = parseFloat(wrkEd.substr(0,2));
        var wrkEd_mn= parseFloat(wrkEd.substr(2,2));

        var msg='';
    if ((wrkSt_hr > wrkEd_hr) || ((wrkSt_hr == wrkEd_hr) && (wrkSt_mn >= wrkEd_mn)) )
    {

        msg+='shift overnight selected';                
    }   

if (wrkEd_hr>12){wrkEd_hr-=12;}
if (wrkSt_hr >12){wrkSt_hr -=12;}
if (brkSt_hr>12){brkSt_hr-=12;}
if (brkEd_hr>12){brkEd_hr-=12;}

var Breakdiff = ((brkEd_hr - brkSt_hr)*60) + (brkEd_mn - brkSt_mn);
var Workdiff_tot = ((wrkEd_hr- wrkSt_hr)*60) + (wrkEd_mn -wrkSt_mn); 
var Shiftdiff = Workdiff_tot - Breakdiff; 

if (Shiftdiff > 480) //8hours = 8*60 = 480 min
 {
  msg+='Time greater than 8 hrs';  
 }
 if (Shiftdiff < 240) //4 hours = 4*60 = 240 min
 {
 msg+='Time less than 4 hrs'; 
 }
```

Please help me with the logic for checking breaks and work time. Thx for any help in advance!

Comment: If these times span across more than one day, you will need to also have the date as well as the time there.

Comment: @Dutchie : This may seem odd, but the date is not to be used in my code. So if user enters 2200 to 0400 (10:00p to 04:00a), only the time is used.So it's independent of date. Thx anyway:)

Comment: Then if the hour is 00-04, you need to add 24 to it to make it LATER than 2300

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate(start, breakStart, breakEnd, end) {
  var minutes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    var time = arguments[i];
    if (!/^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])[0-5]\d$/.test(time)) {
      throw new Error("Invalid time " + time);
    }
    var minute = minutes[i] = time.substring(0, 2) * 60 + +time.substring(2);
    if (i && minute < minutes[i - 1]) {  // Take into account times that cross midnight.
      minutes[i] = (minute += 24*60);
    }
    if (i && minute <= minutes[i - 1]) {
      throw new Error("Out of order " + arguments[i - 1] + " and " + time);
    }
  }
  if (minutes[3] - minutes[0] > 8*60) { throw new Error("Shift too long"); }
  if (minutes[3] - minutes[0] > 4*60) { throw new Error("Shift too short"); }
}
```